# Converting a char* returned by C API to C++ string

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

I found this code in a C++ header-only wrapper around a C API I'm working with:

```
static string GetString(const char* chString)
{
    string strValue;
    if (NULL != chString)
    {
        strValue.swap(string (chString));
        releaseMemory((void*&)chString);
        chString = NULL;
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

I suppose the author is trying to give the string `strValue` ownership of `chString` and then free the empty buffer. I suspect this is very wrong (including it being const char*), but it actually seems to work with MSVC 12. At least I haven't seen it crash spectacularly yet.

Assuming that the C API and the C++ library are using the same heap (so that the string can reallocate the buffer if necessary and eventually release it), is there a way to properly achieve this? How about this?

```
template <typename T> struct Deleter { void operator()(T o) { releaseMemory((void*&)o); } };

static std::string GetString(char* chString)
{
    if (NULL == chString)
        return std::string();
    return std::string(std::unique_ptr<char[], Deleter<char[]>>(chString).get());
}
```

Again, assuming the C API is using the same heap as std::string.

If that's also very wrong, then is there an immutable, owning C-style string wrapper? Something like `string_view` but immutable (so `const char*` input would be ok) and owning (so it deletes the C string, possibly with a custom deleter, in its dtor)?

Comment: The C API should document what is that string, and who is responsible for `free`-ing it if it has been `malloc`-ed somehow.

Comment: `std::string` doesn't take ownership of the buffer pointed to by `chString`. It copies it.

Comment: `strValue.swap(string (chString));` is an unnecessary complication of `strValue = chString;`.

Comment: The `unique_ptr` approach is wrong because it uses `delete []` when it should be using `releaseMemory`. Also there is no taking ownership. The `GetString` creates a copy of the `const char *` and then destroys the original, in a weird way. `chString = NULL;` is also completely pointless.

Comment: Creating a temporary `unique_ptr` will not help extend the life-time of your buffer in any way. It will be destroyed at the end of the expression.

Comment: From the original code it seems clear the caller is responsible for `releaseMemory`-ing the string.

Comment: To be precise, is it the temporary string copying chString, and then strValue is swapping buffer with the temporary string?

Comment: @MattChambers Yes. And like molbdnilo said, you get essentially the same result if you just assign `chString` directly to `strValue`.

Comment: To address the last question, could I just copy the string_view source code and replace the pointers with a shared_ptr<char*>, or does something like that already exist?

Comment: @MattChambers: that would not address the issue of needing to release the original pointer after using its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose the author is trying to give the string `strValue` ownership of `chString` and then free the empty buffer.

No.  It makes an (inefficient and error-prone) copy of the character data pointed to by `chString`, then releases the memory pointed to by `chString` (which will be skipped if the copy throws an exception), and then returns the copy.

> Assuming that the C API and the C++ library are using the same heap

That is not a correct assumption, or even a necessary one.  The copy can use whatever heap it wants.

> is there a way to properly achieve this? How about this?

You are on the right track to use a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom `deleter`, but there is no reason to use the `T[]` array specialization of `std::unique_ptr`.

The code can be simplified to something more like this:

```
void Deleter(char* o) { releaseMemory((void*&)o); }

static std::string GetString(char* chString)
{
    std::string strValue;
    if (chString) {
        std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&Deleter)>(chString, &Deleter);
        strValue = chString;
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

Or, just get rid of the check for `chString` being null, it is not actually needed.  `std::string` can be constructed from a null `char*`, and `std::unique_ptr` will not call its `deleter` with a null pointer:

```
void Deleter(char* o) { releaseMemory((void*&)o); }

static std::string GetString(char* chString)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&Deleter)>(chString, &Deleter);
    return std::string(chString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this seem like a good solution for my last question (and ultimate goal of being able to use a char* like a string without copying it)?

```
template <typename DeleterT = std::default_delete<const char*>>
class c_str_view
{
    public:
    unique_ptr<const char*, DeleterT> strPtr_;
    size_t len_;

    c_str_view() {}
    c_str_view(const char* charPtr) : strPtr_(charPtr), len_(strlen(charPtr)) {}
    c_str_view(const char* charPtr, size_t len) : strPtr_(charPtr), len_(len) {}

    operator std::string_view () const
    {
        return string_view(strPtr_.get(), len_);
    }
};
```

If so, is there a good reason this isn't in the upcoming standard since string_view is coming? It only makes sense with string_view of course, since any conversion to std::string would cause a copy and make the whole exercise pointless.

Here's a test:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9046eb22b10a1d87

Comment: "*Does this seem like a good solution for my last question*" - No.  First off, this should have been added to your question instead of posted as an answer.  And second, it doesn't address the issue of releasing the original `char*` memory properly with `releaseMemory()`.  In fact, this code would take ownership of the `char*` and try to release it with `delete[]` instead. You can't use `delete` with memory from a C-based API.

Comment: Taking ownership is the purpose. The C API is giving the caller ownership; a class like this would take it and return it rather than being required to make a copy and free the original before returning. I made it templated especially so I could use the `releaseMemory()` custom deleter. (this IS an attempt to answer my last question, but I will certainly prefer other anwers to my own if they are more comprehensive)

Comment: In the template you showed, you are accepting a custom `deleter` *type* as a template parameter, but you are not constructing the `std::unique_ptr` with an actual `deleter` *object*. If you read the `std:::unique_ptr` documentation , you should pass the actual deleter as a constructor parameter, not just a template parameter (which defines the constructor parameter's type)

Comment: Are you sure about that? GCC seems to use the deleter without passing it explicitly (I don't use custom deleters very often!); will edit answer with test code

Comment: [read the `std::unique_ptr` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). If you don't pass a deleter in the constructor, a default one is value-initialized using the type specified in the template. That is fine when the deleter is a struct/class with an overridden `operator()`, but that is not fine when the deleter is a plain function or a lambda. So it is best to always pass a custom deleter as a constructor parameter so you know what you are getting.

Comment: Ah, so there is some actually an advantage to using the functor instead of a plain function. Thanks for the clarification. I did read the unique_ptr documentation, but it doesn't make it clear that default value-initialization is  a problem for function pointers but not functors.

Comment: When using a plain function as the deleter, how do you expect the compiler to value-initialize a default function? It can't. So you have to explicitly pass in the function pointer in the constructor